Crowdsec on Debian 12 (Bookworm): Which Firewall-Bouncer is the right one?
I want to install Crowdsec on my Debian 12 (Bookworm) machine.
I have a choice of several of available bouncers. I need clarity as to which bouncer is the right one.
 1. host-firewall-bouncer-dshb
 2. crowdsec-firewall-bouncer
 3. crowdsec-firewall-bouncer-iptables
 4. crowdsec-firewall-bouncer-nftables

Which one should I use?

The one that best matches your host based firewall. Are you still  using iptables or is your system on the (default) nftables ? https://wiki.debian.org/nftables
